atan2 function to find 2 circles centers from 2 points that are less than $2r$ apart
Given 2 points $p$, $q$, and $r$ that are less than $2r$ apart, where $r$ is the radius of a circle. I am asked to find 2 circles centers $c_1$ and $c_2$ that are where the first center is less than $2r$ apart as well.

I though about it as follows:

Find the midpoint $m$ that has $(m_x, m_y)$ coordinates from line segment connecting points $p$ and $q$:

$$(m_x, m_y) = (p.x + q.x) / 2, (p.y + q.y) / 2$$
We can find the distance the midpoint from the center $c1$ as follows, where $distCM$ is the distance to $CM$ point on the line segment connecting $p$ and $q$:
$$distCM = \sqrt{(r ^2- (dist(p, q) / 2)^2)}$$

Question:From here after, I am confused as to how we can find the actual coordinates of $c_1$ and $c_2$, but I will list the steps:

find angle $\alpha$ between points $p$ and $q$ as follows using $\alpha = atan2(p.y - q.y, q.x - p.x)$.
Center of $c_1 = (m_x - distCM * sin(\alpha), m_y - distCM * cos(\alpha))$
Center of $c_2 = (m_x + distCM * sin(\alpha), m_y + distCM * cos(\alpha))$

If you could provide more steps why the 3 steps above make sense? For example, why we did not use $\alpha = atan2(p.y - q.y,  p.x - q.x)$? Also I am not getting the intuition behind  $c_1 = (m_x - distCM * sin(\alpha), m_y - distCM * cos(\alpha))$?

You don't actually need any trig functions. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1781546/139123

$atan2(p_y - q_y, q_x - p_x)$ gives you the angle you need to rotate $pq$ around $q$ (or any other point on the line passing through $p$ and $q$) ccw so that $pq$ lies on a horizontal line with $p$ to the left of $q$. If the angle is negative, then the rotation is cw. Having obtained this angle, the formulas for $c_1$ and $c_2$ follow from simple geometry. Consider for example, a case where $p_y - q_y>0$ and $q_x - p_x<0$:

Here $d=distCM$ for convenience, $\alpha=atan2(p_y - q_y, q_x - p_x)$. It should be clear from the picture that $c_{1x}=m_x-dcos(\alpha-\pi/2)=m_x-dsin(\alpha)$, $c_{1y}=m_y+dsin(\alpha-\pi/2)=m_y-dcos(\alpha)$.
If you use $atan2(p_y - q_y, p_x-q_x)$ instead, you'll obtain the angle you need to rotate $pq$ around $q$ cw so it lies on a horizontal line with $p$ to the right of $q$. In the picture above it corresponds to the angle $\pi-\alpha$.
As some extra: it's probably less confusing to solve this problem in the complex plane. First, consider a special case where one center $c_1'$ is in the origin (so $c_1'=0$) and the other center $c_2'$ lies on the positive real axis. Then the points of intersection of the circles are $p'=re^{i\theta}$, $q'=re^{-i\theta}$ for some $\theta\in (0,\pi/2)$. Hence, $c_2'=2rcos(\theta)$. The general case can be obtained by first rotating everything around origin ccw by some angle $\beta\in [0,2\pi)$ and then translating everything by some complex number $c$. After this transformation you get: $$\begin{cases}
p=re^{i\theta}e^{i\beta}+c\\
q=re^{-i\theta}e^{i\beta}+c\\
c_1=c\\
c_2=2rcos(\theta)e^{i\beta}+c
\end{cases}$$
Therefore, $p-q=2rie^{i\beta}sin(\theta)$, so $sin(\theta)=\frac{|p-q|}{2r}$ and $cos(\theta)=\sqrt{1-sin^2(\theta)}$ (positive, since $\theta\in (0,\pi/2) )$. Then, $e^{i\beta}=\frac{p-q}{2risin(\theta)}=\frac{q-p}{|p-q|}i$. Thus, $c_1=c=\frac{p+q}{2}-rcos(\theta)e^{i\beta}$ and $c_2=2rcos(\theta)e^{i\beta}+c=\frac{p+q}{2}+rcos(\theta)e^{i\beta}$. Taking real and imaginary parts , you get the coordinates. Also note, that in your original notation, $m=\frac{p+q}{2}$, $distCM=rcos(\theta)$, and $\alpha=\pi/2-\beta$, so if you plug this into the equations for $c_1$ and $c_2$, you'll obtain the formulas from your post.
